# how to prevent viewed pages after logout using servlet and jsp

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets, logout

This is my first query in this website. Hope you guys will help to finish my project. Thnx in advance.

I pasted my complete code of my project. I want a solution (i.e.) after clicking logout button, user should navigate to login page and when he tries to click back button, he should not go to previous page and should be in same login page.

**index.jsp**

```
            <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
                pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
                    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
                    <html>
                    <head>
                    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
                    <title>Login</title>

                    <style type="text/css">
                    .header {
                width: 250px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: #6495ED;
            font-family: verdana;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .header2 {
            width: 250px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: "#FFE4B5";
            font-family: verdana;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        <%String name = (String) request.getAttribute("status");%>
        var alertMsg = "<%=name%>
            ";
            if (alertMsg != "null" && alertMsg != '') {
                alert(alertMsg);
            }
        </script>


        <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/gen_validatorv4.js"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
        </head>
        <body>

            <form name="login" action="LoginServlet" method="post">

                <center>
                    <a href="index.jsp" class="header2" style="background-color: #FFE4B5";>Home</a>
                </center>



                <center>
                    <table
                        style="background-color: #CAE1FF; border-color: 1px solid red;">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" class="header" colspan="2">Login</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr height="50px">
                            <td align="" class=""
                                style="padding-left: 10px; font-family: tohoma;">Username</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="username" style="width: 150px;" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr height="50px">
                            <td align="" class=""
                                style="padding-left: 10px; font-family: tohoma;">Password</td>
                            <td><input type="password" name="password"
                                style="width: 150px;" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr height="50px">
                            <td></td>
                            <td align="center" colspan="0">
                                <table style="width: 100%;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="left"><input type="submit" name="submit"
                                            value="Login"
                                            style="width: 60px; height: 25px; background: #436EEE; color: white !important; border: 1px solid #0000EE;; border-radius: 2;" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td><input type="reset" value="Cancel"
                                            style="width: 60px; height: 25px; background: #436EEE; color: white !important; border: 1px solid #0000EE;; border-radius: 2;" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td><a href="register.jsp">New User?</a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </center>
            </form>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                var formValidator = new Validator("login");
                formValidator.addValidation("username", "req",
                        "Please enter your User Name");
                formValidator.addValidation("password", "req",
                        "Please enter your Password");
            </script>

        </body>
        </html>
```

**LoginServlet.java**

```
            package pack;

        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.sql.Connection;
        import java.sql.DriverManager;
        import java.sql.ResultSet;
        import java.sql.Statement;

        import javax.servlet.Filter;
        import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
        import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
        import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
        import javax.servlet.ServletException;
        import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
        import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
        import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

        /**
         * Servlet implementation class LoginServlet
         */
        @WebServlet("/LoginServlet")
        public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet implements Filter {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            /**
             * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
             */
            public LoginServlet() {
                super();
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            }

            /**
             * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
             *      response)
             */
            @Override
            protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            /**
             * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
             *      response)
             */
            @Override
            protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
                String loginName = null;
                String loginPass = null;
                String status;
                HttpSession session = request.getSession();
                String username = request.getParameter("username");
                String password = request.getParameter("password");

                String jdbcDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
                String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentdetails";
                String uname = "root";
                String pwd = "admin";

                try {
                    Class.forName(jdbcDriver);
                    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, uname, pwd);
                    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs;
                    String query = "SELECT username, password FROM registration WHERE username = '"
                            + username + "' AND password = '" + password + "'";

                    System.out.println(query);
                    stmt.executeQuery(query);

                    boolean permission = false;
                    rs = stmt.getResultSet();

                    while (rs.next()) {
                        permission = true;
                        loginName = rs.getString("username");
                        loginPass = rs.getString("password");

                    }

                    System.out.println(loginName);
                    System.out.println(loginPass);

                    rs.close();
                    stmt.close();

                    if (permission == true) {
                        request.getSession(true);
                        session.setAttribute("username", loginName);
                        RequestDispatcher redis = request
                                .getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/pages/list.jsp");
                        redis.forward(request, response);

                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Permission denied");
                        status = "Username not yet registered";
                        request.setAttribute("status", status);

                        RequestDispatcher redis = request
                                .getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
                        redis.forward(request, response);

                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
                    FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
                HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
                HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
                if (session != null && session.isNew()) {
                    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
                    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                    response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
                    chain.doFilter(request, response);
                } else {
                    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        }
```

**list.jsp**

```
                <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
                pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
            <html>
            <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
            <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
            <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
            <meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-CACHE">
            <title>Insert title here</title>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function logout() {

                    session.removeAttribute("username");
                    request.getSession().invalidate();
                    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
                }
            </script>
            </head>

            <body>
                <form action="LoginServlet" name = "list">
                    <p><%if(session.getAttribute("username")!=null){
                    %>
                    <%session.getAttribute("username");%></p>
                    <%} %>
                    <input type="button" value = "Logout" onclick="logout();"/>

                </form>
            </body>
            </html>
```

**web.xml**

```
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
                id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
                <display-name>SessionManagement</display-name>
                <servlet>
                    <servlet-name>Session</servlet-name>
                    <servlet-class>pack.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
                </servlet>
                <servlet-mapping>
                    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
                    <url-pattern>/LoginServlet</url-pattern>
                </servlet-mapping>
                <filter>
                    <filter-name>noCacheFilter</filter-name>
                    <filter-class>pack.LoginServlet</filter-class>
                </filter>
                <filter-mapping>
                    <filter-name>noCacheFilter</filter-name>
                    <url-pattern>/list.jsp</url-pattern>
                </filter-mapping>
                <welcome-file-list>
                    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
                </welcome-file-list>
            </web-app>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to disable the "bfcache", forcing the browser to redownload the page - which in turns will detect the user is not logged in anymore and redirect to the login page

Comment: how to disable it dude..

Comment: Usually people asks how to enable it... anyway it seems that using a non-empty  `onunload` function on your `body` tag effectively disables it completely.

Comment: creating a filter alone didn't work for me. With the 'onunload' function it now does. Thanks @thedayofcondor